# jQuery Selectric

Tags: jquery, select

Пытаюсь с помощью Selectric выбрать текущий (выбранный) элемент LI, но ничего не получается, подскажите кто знает как это можно сделать

Есть одна загвоздка, я использую не SELECT и OPTION, а UL и LI :
[Пример Selectric и ul, что я делаю тут](http://www.saitadmin.ru/faili_na_razdacu/selectric.html)

Вот ссылка на Selectric http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/index.html

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста свой код. Каким образом у вас выбирается li? Может можно сделать то что вы хотите без этой библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл примерно похожее решение, вот HTML:

```
<ul class="customOptions">
    <li class="">Select something</li>
    <li class=""><span data-value="value1"> Choice 1</span></li>
    <li class="selected"><span data-value="value2"> Choice 2</span></li>
    <li class=""><span data-value="value2"> Choice 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

JS будет выглядеть так:

```
$(function(){
    $('.customOptions').selectric({
        maxHeight: 300,
        onChange: function(element) {
           alert( $('.selectricItems').find('.selected span').attr('data-value') );
        }
    });
});
```

Ссылка на источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137198/magento-javascript-undefined-is-not-a-function-jquery-selectric